# How to find duplicate lines in a text file, while some may be commented out or have different tokens at the beginning?

Tags: text-processing, uniq

I have a text file with lines that are a mixture like this:

```
###  Comments

# Comments
86.242.200.81 banana.domain.net          # comment
86.242.200.3 orange.domain.net
31.28.225.81 monkey.anotherdomain.net

51.18.33.4 puffin.domainz.com
#31.28.220.80 monkey.anotherdomain.net   # comment
86.242.201.3 orange.domain.net
```

How do I find the host.domain duplicates?

In this case, there are two:  `monkey.anotherdomain.net` and `orange.domain.net`

Taking into account that..

- Trailing comments after the entry need to be ignored, as they may not be on the duplicate.
- If the line is commented out, the duplicate should still be found.
- Differences in IP address should be ignored.

Comment: It seems to be a logic conflict to say that a commented-out line should be ignored, yet still included.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I see what you mean, but I meant the hash at the front commenting the line out should be ignored.  I've edited the question.

Comment: omg, please tell me you're not distributing a hosts file that's so complex you have to write scripts to manage it. That's why we have DNS.

Comment: @WouterVerhelst  It's a hosts file that is not to be used as a hosts file.  It's a record set.

Answer (score 6):

This was a fun one.

First, we need to eliminate *trailing* comments, as in:

```
86.242.200.81 banana.domain.net          # comment
```

We can do that with the following (assuming just spaces, no tabs):

```
sed 's/  *#.*//'
```

If you have tabs in your hosts file, maybe run this first:

```
tr '\t' ' '
```

Then we need to eliminate "comment out this line" comments, which I'm going to define as a single hash character preceding an ip address. We can remove those like this:

```
sed '/^#[0-9]/ s/^#//'
```

Putting the above together gets us:

```
###  Comments

# Comments
86.242.200.81 banana.domain.net
86.242.200.3 orange.domain.net
31.28.225.81 monkey.anotherdomain.net

51.18.33.4 puffin.domainz.com
31.28.220.80 monkey.anotherdomain.net
86.242.201.3 orange.domain.net
```

If we sort this on the second column (`sort -k2`), we get a list sorted by name:

```
86.242.200.81 banana.domain.net
# Comments
###  Comments
31.28.220.80 monkey.anotherdomain.net
31.28.225.81 monkey.anotherdomain.net
86.242.200.3 orange.domain.net
86.242.201.3 orange.domain.net
51.18.33.4 puffin.domainz.com
```

And now we can apply `uniq` to find duplicates, if we tell `uniq` to ignore the first field:

```
uniq -c -f 1
```

Which gives us:

```
  2 
  1 86.242.200.81 banana.domain.net
  1 # Comments
  1 ###  Comments
  2 31.28.220.80 monkey.anotherdomain.net
  2 86.242.200.3 orange.domain.net
  1 51.18.33.4 puffin.domainz.com
```

So if we look for lines with a count of 2 or higher, we have found our duplicates.  Putting this all together we get:

```
#!/bin/sh

tr '\t' ' ' |
sed '
    /^#[0-9]/ s/^#//
    s/  *#.*//
    /^ *$/ d
' |
sort -k2 |
uniq -f 1 -c |
awk '$1 > 1 {print}'
```

The final `awk` statement in the above script looks for lines where the count from `uniq` (field1 ) is `> 1`.

Running the above script looks like [this](http://asciinema.org/a/71ng7s9dnust96yyoi1ho9zer).

Comment: why not just a quick and dirty: `grep -i "[a-z]\\.[a-z]" the-file | awk '{print $2}'|sort | uniq -c|grep -v "1 "`

Comment: I started out on the supposition that he was going to want the ip addresses, and then went from there because I was having so much fun.  And ended up discarding the ip addresses. You should post the simpler solution.

Answer (score 4):

If **actual** comment lines like the ones you've depicted at the beginning of your data exist and are to be ignored, I don't see how point 2 can be satisfied without some kind of assumption around how commented lines that are material can be told apart from commented lines that are to be ignored. I've made the assumption that commented lines that are material contain a period in the second field.

```
awk 'NF && $2 ~ /[.]/{++a[$2]}; 
 END{for (k in a) if(a[k] > 1) print k}' file
orange.domain.net
monkey.anotherdomain.net
```

Answer (score 4):

```
sed 's/\(.\)#.*/\1/' file | cut -f 2 -d\ | sort | uniq -d
```

- Remove comments that are preceded by anything `sed 's/\(.\)#.*/\1/'`
- Filter just the second column `cut -f 2 -d\`
- Sort the lines for the following comparison `sort`
- And only print duplicates `uniq -d`

Note that unless it is a possibility to have a line like

```
86.242.200.81 banana.domain.net#comment
```

You can simplify the above to:

```
cut -f 2 -d\  file | sort | uniq -d
```

as the comment would be considered a third field.

Answer (score 3):

How about the short, easy and straight way?

```
awk '/#*\d/{print $2}' file | sort | uniq -d
```

This allows to report host.domain duplicates even if they are commented out by a hash sign (#).